# What is the correct form (using a comparative adjective) of the sentence 'no other planet is so big as Jupiter'?

Tags: adjectives, comparative

> No other planet is bigger than Jupiter.

or

> Jupiter is bigger than any other planet.

Which of these is the 'correct form', using a comparative adjective, of the following sentence?

> No other planet is so big as Jupiter.

Comment: I just want to interchange the degree of comparison. (From positive to comparative)

Comment: Then please intercahnge 'jupiter is bigger than any other planet' to positive form.

Comment: Sir actually i am not a native English speaker. I am from india and i am trying to learn English. But the all books i have read till date follows different rules . So i have posted this question as stack exchange is the best platform to ask english related questions.

Comment: If it possible i will send you some picture from the books as well. since i am new member to this platform i am facing some problems.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually, the two answers do not mean the same thing. If there is another planet the same size as Jupiter, then the first is still correct, as is the original sentence. However, the second answer is wrong. (If we want to paraphrase without a negative then we need *every other planet is smaller than Jupiter*, or somat like that)

Comment: @sumelic You're right (assuming pragmatics rules out 'No other planet is [as] big as Jupiter' = 'Some are smaller, some are bigger'). It's a test of logic rather than grammar per se. I was thrown by 'correct form' into expecting a grammatical problem with one. / In great need of a holiday.

Answer (score 1):

Both example sentences are grammatically and semantically correct.  The second example sentence sounds more natural to my (American) ear.

Because Jupiter is not bigger than itself, the first example sentence can be simplified to:

> No planet is bigger than Jupiter.

If you choose to use a superlative (instead of a comparative adjective), you can simplify the second example sentence to:

> Jupiter is the biggest planet.

Answer (score 0):

*No other planet is bigger than Jupiter.*

The comparision can be between actions, objects or events their form or function, virtues or attributes  e.g.,

No runner faster than Bolt ;

No love edifice grander than the Taj ;

No fruit sweeter than mango ;

So daring in love, and so dauntless in war, 
Have ye e’er heard of gallant like young Lochinvar? etc..

Comment: Hello, Narasimham. Please visit the Help Center to find out more about answers considered valuable on ELU. Being 'right' is rarely sufficient; supporting evidence is almost always a requisite. Where the answer is deemed too obvious to need such supporting evidence on a site aimed at linguists, the proper response is to close-vote the question.